# Prove two points in a space must lie in different components

Tags: general-topology

In the $R^{2}$ space,let $A_{1}=\left\{(x,1）|x\in [0,1] \right\}$ ,$A_{2}=\left\{(x,\dfrac {1}{2}）|x\in [0,1] \right\}$,$A_{2}=\left\{(x,\dfrac {1}{3}）|x\in [0,1] \right\}$ $\ldots$ Let $Y=\cup^{\infty}_{n=1} A_{n}\cup {(0,0)}\cup {(0,1)}$.
Prove that $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$ lie in different components of $X$,but if you have a separation of $Y$ which are two disjoint open sets,then $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ must both lie in one of them.

I think $(0,1)$ itself is the component of $Y$ and so is  $(0,0)$.But i don't know how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $X=Y$. Even so, the statement of your problem is incorrect, since $(0,1)\in A_1$, $(0,0)\in A_1^c$, and $A_1$ is open in $Y$ as $$A_1=Y\cap \bigcup_{x\in [0,1]}B\left((x,1),\tfrac{1}{3}\right),$$ where $B\left((a,b),\epsilon\right)$ is the open ball around $(a,b)$ of radius $\epsilon$. But $A_1^c$ is also open in $Y$ as $$A_1^c=Y\cap \bigcup_{x\in [0,1]}B\left((x,0),\tfrac{3}{4}\right).$$ This shows that $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$ both lie in different components of $Y$, via the separation $A_1$ and $A_1^c$.

I would then assume you meant to write $(1,0)$ rather than $(0,1)$. In this case, you've said that you think the components for both $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ must be singleton sets, i.e., $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(1,0)\}$, respectively. Considering just the component $C$ of $(0,0)$, can you find a separation of $C$ if you assume it contains another point $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$?

To help you along, what would such an $(a,b)$ have to look like?

Comment: Thank you very much.I've proved first question using your method. But I'm stuck by the second question. I think the separation of $X$ should always be the horizontal line to cut the graph off ,so $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ must line in the same separation. I don't know how to prove it strictly.

Comment: Glad to help! But for the second part, what you've said isn't exactly true, since you could make your open set all of the odd $A_i$, so you have to be careful. To show $(1,0)$ [not $(0,1)$!] and $(0,0)$ must be in the same component, I recommend assuming they weren't, for a contradiction. The fault will have something to do with the fact any neighborhood around each point will intersect infinitely many $A_i$, including many which both will intersect.